# Ubuntu server, 8 relay usb board need to turn on more than one at ounce

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting, serial-port

I bought a china usb 8 relay switch board. It shows up in ubuntu server as a serial device. I figured out the commands to get it to work.

*Set Baud Rate of relay board

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 -parity cs8 -cstopb
```

To start relay controller:

```
echo -e -n "\x50" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To activate relay for commands:

```
echo -e -n "\x51" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To turn on relay

```
echo -e -n "\x(number)" > /dev/ttyUSB0*
```

But my issue is if I turn on relay 1 (/x01) and then turn on relay 2 (/x02) relay 1 turns off. I'm trying to automate and will need it to turn on more than one relay at a time. I went thru with testers and started mapping each number, Like 03 turns on relay 01 and 02. But there has to be an easier way. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Without knowing what relay board you have, this question is impossible to answer. We don't even know if the board is capable of having more than one relay on at the time.

Comment: Here's the Board, and echo -e -n "\x00" > /dev/ttyUSB0 Turns them all on.  
    http://www.icstation.com/icstation-channel-icse014a-micro-switch-relay-module-upper-computer-control-board-icse014a-p-5185.html

Comment: Read the one customer/user **`Feedback`** on use of this board at http://www.icstation.com/icstation-channel-icse014a-micro-switch-relay-module-upper-computer-control-board-icse014a-p-5185.html   "*To turn on relay ...*" -- No, each command does much more than that. You've also provided conflicting (incorrect?) information for commands & results.  The control byte specifies the (inverted?) state for all eight relays at once. So the host has to maintain the state of each relay in order construct a new value to send, otherwise you'll inadvertently turn off (or on) other relays.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bitwise control.

For example to turn on only port 0 (the first), you send \xFE.

```
(echo "obase=16" ; echo $((255 ^ 1)))|bc| sed -e 's/^/\\x/'
0xFE
```

Essentially take 255 and subtract these values for each port you wish to start:
|Port|Number|
|--| ---|
|0|1|
|1|2|
|2|4|
|3|8|
|4|16|
|5|32|
|6|64|
|7|128|

To turn relay 1, 4, 5, and 7 you need to send:

```
255 (all 8 bits stop)  - 2 (bit 1 start) - 16 (bit 4 start) - 128 (bit 7 start) = 109.
```

In hex 109 is 6D, so send \x6D to the device.

Answer (score 0):

A more visual example:

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    varfolder=/dev/shm
    
    for i in $(find -L /sys/bus/usb/devices/ -maxdepth 2 -name "ttyUSB*"); do
            usb=$(egrep -i "2303" $i/../modalias >/dev/null && echo "${i##*/}")
    check=$(grep PRODUCT= /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/$usb/../uevent)
    if [ "$check" == "PRODUCT=67b/2303/300" ]; then
    releport=/dev/$usb
    fi
       done
    
    ## this word "modif" depends on the linux interface language
    modf_time=$(stat /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/$usb | grep  modif)
    init_time=$(<$varfolder/init_usb_relay)
    
    if [ "$modf_time" != "$init_time" ] ; then 
    echo -e -n "\x50" > $releport
    echo -e -n "\x51" > $releport
    echo $modf_time > "$varfolder/init_usb_relay"
    fi
    
    # 87654321
    # turn off 6 and 5 relay
    relstatusbin=11001111
    relstatus16=$(echo "ibase=2;obase=10000;$relstatusbin"|bc)
    echo -e -n "\x$relstatus16" > $releport
```

Known issues:

- If the USB wire does not carry enough electricity to hold the relay coil then the relay will not energize. In this case, additional power is required. Or simultaneously turn off a smaller number of relays.
- Contacts can stick.
- Contacts may burn.
- If the device stopped accepting commands, then in order not to reboot Linux, you need to remove the device `rm -f /dev/ttyUSB0`